# Getting inputs to a function from a python object

Tags: python, function, python-object

I have a class. This class has a list of functions that are to be evaluated by a different program.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.functions_to_evaluate = []
```

There is a function that adds functions to an instance of SomeClass, via something like:

```
new_function = check_number(5)
SomeClassInstance.functions_to_evaluate.append(new_function)
```

Where check_number is a function that will check if number is greater than 10, let's say.

If I take SomeClassInstance.functions_to_evaluate and print it, I get a bunch of python objects, like so:

```
<some_library.check_number object at 0x07B35B90>
```

I am wondering if it is possible for me to extract the input given to check_number, so something like:

SomeClassInstance.functions_to_evaluate[0].python_feature() that will return "5" or whatever the input to check_number was to me.

Comment: Yes, it can be possible, but that depends on the definiton of `check_number()`. Please edit your question and add the `check_number` definition.

Comment: In general, though, no, the return value of a function doesn't know anything about how the function was called, which function was called, or even that it *is* the return value of any particular function.

Comment: `new_function` is not a function, it's an evaluation (i.e., the `return` value) *of* the `check_number` function.

Comment: i added check_number, but I do not think it has what is needed. In what way does check_number need to be written to enable this ability @nosklo

Comment: The `check_number` function you added will always return True or False, it will never return `<some_library.check_number object at 0x07B35B90>`.

Comment: Ah, sorry - will edit my question.

Comment: @RebeccaK375 the correct definition of `check_number` is **key** to what you want, since the value you want to retrieve (`5`) was passed to it when you called `check_number(5)` . We need to see inside that function, if that value was discarded or stored somewhere.

Comment: In an attempt to simplify the question, I made a mistake (and figured out how to do what I originally wanted to do), but I will leave the question as is because someone answered with how to do it with a closure method (and I think that adds knowledge to stack overflow, so I will leave the question up instead of deleting it.) Thank you!

Comment: The `check_number` object created by your library probably returns some object of a class that implements the `__call__` method. This is how `functools.partial` works. That gives you an object that is callable just like a function. A closure is not exactly the same, but the principle is similar. Python doesn't have truely private instance variables, so it's certainly possible to extract the arguments enclosed in the `check_number` callable, but you have to investigate the source code for that class to find out exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard library [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which creates a new partially applied function *.

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def check_number(input):
...     return input > 10
>>> fn = partial(check_number, 5)
>>> fn.args  # this attribute gives you back the bound arguments, as a tuple.
(5,)
>>> fn()  # calls the function with the bound arguments.
False
```

*: actually the `partial` object is not a `function` instance, but it is a callable, and from a duck-type perspective it's a function.

Answer (score 1):

If `new_function = check_number(5)` is a closure, then you can extract this value using `__closure__[0].cell_contents`:

Example:

```
def foo(x):
    def inn(y):
        return x
    return inn

s = foo(5)
print(s.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
```

Output:

> `5`

Answer (score 1):

I understand your confusion, but:

```
new_function = check_number(5)
```

Is calling the function, and the `new_function` variable gets assigned the **return value** of the function.

If you have this `check_number` function:

```
def check_number(input):
    return input > 10
```

Then it will return `False`, and `new_function` will be `False`. Never `<some_library.check_number object at 0x07B35B90>`.

If you're getting `<some_library.check_number object at 0x07B35B90>`  then your `check_number()` function is returning something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to skin this cat. But I'd observe first and foremost that you're not adding *python function objects* to the `functions_to_evaluate` list, you're adding the evaluations *of* functions.

You could simply add a `tuple` of `function, args` to the list:

```
SomeClassInstace.functions_to_evaluate.append((check_number, 5))
```

And then you can:

```
for f, args in SomeClassInstance.functions_to_evaluate:
    print(args)
```